What is the meaning of the "&" character "ad_access_filter" parameter of the sssd.conf configuration file
Here and there, I see a & character at the beginning of the ad_access_filter parameter.
But I see no & character in the ad_access_filter parameter of the sssd-ad manual :
$ man sssd-ad | sed -n '/ad_access_filter/,/Default:/ p'
       ad_access_filter (string)
           This option specifies LDAP access control filter that the user must match in order to be allowed access. Please note that the “access_provider” option must be
           explicitly set to “ad” in order for this option to have an effect.

           The option also supports specifying different filters per domain or forest. This extended filter would consist of: “KEYWORD:NAME:FILTER”. The keyword can be either
           “DOM”, “FOREST” or missing.

           If the keyword equals to “DOM” or is missing, then “NAME” specifies the domain or subdomain the filter applies to. If the keyword equals to “FOREST”, then the filter
           equals to all domains from the forest specified by “NAME”.

           Multiple filters can be separated with the “?”  character, similarly to how search bases work.

           Nested group membership must be searched for using a special OID “:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:” in addition to the full DOM:domain.example.org: syntax to ensure the parser
           does not attempt to interpret the colon characters associated with the OID. If you do not use this OID then nested group membership will not be resolved. See usage
           example below and refer here for further information about the OID: [MS-ADTS] section LDAP extensions[2]

           The most specific match is always used. For example, if the option specified filter for a domain the user is a member of and a global filter, the per-domain filter
           would be applied. If there are more matches with the same specification, the first one is used.

           Examples:

               # apply filter on domain called dom1 only:
               dom1:(memberOf=cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=dom1,dc=com)

               # apply filter on domain called dom2 only:
               DOM:dom2:(memberOf=cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=dom2,dc=com)

               # apply filter on forest called EXAMPLE.COM only:
               FOREST:EXAMPLE.COM:(memberOf=cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com)

               # apply filter for a member of a nested group in dom1:
               DOM:dom1:(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=nestedgroup,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com)

           Default: Not set
$

What is the meaning of the & character at the beginning of the ad_access_filter parameter ?

I think it's just a logical AND operator - in "Polish" (prefix) notation. See for example this related [SO] question Understanding LDAP OR filter
